# Draw a comet in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, drawing, core-graphics

The requirement is very simple.

As the user moves his fingers a comet is drawn.
I have seen some tutorials and have implemented few of them, now writing in here just to have an expert opinion.

http://soulwithmobiletechnology.blogspot.com/2011/06/redo-undo-in-paint-feature.html

This tutorial teaches how to draw and undo the line that is being drawn.
Problem with it is the comet needs to have some cool effects; which means the ends/tails vanishes in an fadeout fashion.

How can this be achieved and whether the technique that I am following is an appropriate one ?

**just for info:**

**Comet** is a Noun:
A celestial object consisting of a nucleus of ice and dust and, when near the sun, ***a “tail” of gas and dust particles pointing away...***

The first screen shot makes some sense regarding the Comet basic effects

[image: This screen shot makes some sense regarding the Comet basic effects]

where as the second image doesn't make sense at all and the image that is repeated to generate the comet effect is very clear. which is highly undesirable.

[image: this image doesn't make sense at all and the image that is repeated to generate the comet effect is very clear. which is highly undesirable.]

Comment: "...have implemented few of them..." Mind showing us what you've done so far?

Comment: one approach is to draw comet like images on each touch location that that hides itself with an fadeout effect. Which i didnt found enough appropriate as there were many lags due to UIPanGesture more over it is completely image based. The second approach to draw a broad line that will hide itself, sounded interesting; and my implementation for that is not much different then the undo functionality but in reverse order (last in first out).

Comment: i don't know why people have downvoted the question. @People Mind giving comments while down voting ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps try using a [CAEmitterLayer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAEmitterLayer_class/Reference/Reference.html) and [CAEmitterCell](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAEmitterCell_class/Reference/Reference.html).

Here's also a good [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/6063/uikit-particle-systems-in-ios-5-tutorial) on it from Ray Wenderlich's site.

Comment: thanks its pretty much the same what I already have implemented as shown in the images in question... the only difference is; the author has played much with the images. And if you play the example code and swipe very fast you will see again how it misses the spaces in between. Any turn around to fill out those missing spaces ?

Comment: +1 for using CAEmitterLayer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use particle effects in [Cocos2d](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/). Using particle effects, you can make something pretty fancy.

Comment: As I don't have much knowledge regarding the Cocos2D and have to convert the whole app to Cocos2D so I prefer it to be done in Cocoa. Any alternate to that ?